# Handling classes with many versions, adapter or factory?

Tags: php

I am working with a [third party library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib) that has new versions of the same(mostly) classes every 3-4 months. I don't want to have to update every class that uses them every time a new version is out.

The library is structured in the following manner where the service uses the class of the same version.

`v201609/myClass
v201609/myService
v201701/myClass
v201701/myService`

I can't feed an adapter into the service, so I will have to construct the actual class. To illustrate:
`$myService->handle(new MyClass);`

My solution where factories use and build the actual classes:
`(MyServiceFactory::build())->handle(MyClassFactory::fromModel($myModel));`

So every time a new version of the classes are published, I will have to update all my factories.

**Questions:**

1. Is this the optimal approach to this problem?
2. Is factory the correct naming convention to this approach?

Comment: 1. It's far from optimal. 2. why don't you use `composer` to manage library versions? What you described here would be solved by a single `composer update` CLI command and version is managed via `composer.json` file. Library you linked even contains a `composer.json` file which lets you manage it via `composer`. [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/) for info on what composer is, if you didn't know.

Comment: Yes I am using composer, but you can see in their example that even in each release, multiple versions of the classes are included. Why do they include old versions in new releases? Because the API supports old versions for months before being deprecated.

Comment: You're right, they really do. In that case, it really looks like your approach is completely fine. I admit I'd do it like you did it. Let's see if someone has a better idea. My first comment is completely wrong.

Comment: Haven't got any real experience doing this, but couldn't you do a check for the same class-structure, and just pull the latest version?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I was thinking about something similar but how would I handle breaking changes? It may not be ideal to handle the checking during execution, so maybe unit testing? But that seems manual. Then, is it really better than the solution in the question?

Comment: Without digging too much into the code, could you not just drop in a different autoloader?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that they use version number in any position of namespace.
In my opinion, your solution is not that bad.

The problem is when you want you [type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) in code, but this could generate only drawback. Then the same go to `Factories`. Then every few month you need to update them.

Autoloader itself, won't resolve this, as you still declared class in factory. Additionally, you want omit problem coupling project to version - in result, you will omit everywhere type declaration for this objects.

Good advice is to use Integration testing (PHPUnit), this will find any problem with Data structure after update, you will need this.

Second advice - in constructor, send actual version to load and use loading by string name

> return new $fullClassName()

with correct class name and version. Then you will change this only in you config file, for given factory. Don't use `use` for following classes then.

I hope, this will fully resolve you problem.

Comment: I have been advice by the library developers to do a find and replace across my code to update the version numbers. As for breaking changes, I was advice to read the breaking change documentation. Your approach is good but it wouldn't work with PHPStorm's code hinting.

Comment: If you are using annotation `@return` on factory, then you only need correctly mark used factory in places by mentioned type definition. The PHP storm should handle everything. About code hinting in declarations of methods/functions, you are correct - if you want to use that, you will need to  update all code in project. Other solution, could be to create repository as adapter, where you extends  given classes with other namespaces - if they don't you `final` on classes, or have strange dependency - this could work too.

Answer (score 1):

From my point, this namespacing system is ridiculous. They publish their library with a version tag, and classes in it are this version only. When you decide to upgrade, you also receive one version only. Like any other library.

So now I've vomitted this system, how to fix it ?

One solution is to use an event handler in composer, such as `post-package-update` to dump the latest version number into a file. Then your factory read this file and load the correct version of the library

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is Google who are wrong here. They use semantic tagging in their GitHub repo, so what they *should* be telling people is to install the correct version using composer, instead of their bad solution where the latest tagged version on github contains 3 or 4 older versions in a namespaced folder.

So having said that, your idea ain't all that bad. A quick find and replace would also work.

I would raise an issue on their Github and explain why they should be using the Git & composer tags!